# A Website blocked on my network?

Tags: networking

I have a problem accessing www.inc.com, and only this website. I can access this site outside of my home without a problem but at home I get what looks like a site map, nothing else. This is happening on all the computers on our network.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Probably it is, as your question indicates, blocked by your IT group.  You should contact them and see if this is the case and if they're willing to work with you on it.

Another thing might be that your company's proxy/firewall is just having a problem with the sight.  In either case, talk with them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows you may wish to open cmd.exe and do an `ipconfig /flushdns`.

You may also want to switch your dns resolvers to either 4.2.2.1/4.2.2.2 or 208.67.222.222/ 208.67.220.220.

Another alternative would be accessing it through a proxy.